# How to create WCF object of 2 WCF service dynamically based on endpoint name?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am consuming 2 WCF service in 1 WCF service.

```
using WcfService.Server1;
using WcfService.Server2;
```

I am calling a function that is returning endpoint name of suitable WCF service based on some logic. How to create object of WCF service based on endpoint name dynamically?

In below code I created WCF object of "Server1" WCF service but suppose method returns endpoint name "Server2Endpoint" then it would be a problem because I am referring WcfService.Server1

```
WcfService.Server1.MatrixCalculationClient Proxy1 = new WcfService.Server1.MatrixCalculationClient("Server1Endpoint");
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what your problem is. Do you get any errors? Your posted line of code seems to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Problem is both the WCF service are identical but of different type

Comment: What is identical? Do they share a common interface?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both WCF services implements same interface, e.g. `IWCFService`.

Then I believe you will have to use either your own proxy class (which implements `IWCFService` independently of `Server1` or `Server2`) or construct channel manually using `ChannelFactory<IWCFService>`.

In both cases you can pass name of the endpoint to the proper constructors and then everything will work if app.config file contains correct definition of these endpoints (same contract).